# Activity is not recreated when orientation changes from landscape to reverse-landscape

Tags: android

I have an activity that holds a fragment with a texture view.

The texture view displays camera stream.
I need to set camera orientation appropriatelly and there is difference between landscape and reverse-landscape orientation.

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(degrees);
```

However, when device orientation changes from landscape to reverse-landscape.

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

The activity is not recreated and I have no way to find out when orientation changes. `onConfigurationChanged` is not triggered either.

Is there another event that is triggered in this case?

Comment: Have you added `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` to the element activity in your manifest?

Comment: Yes, it does not have any effect.